# How can I make the most out of a reliable, close, helpful player in a group of players new to the system?

Tags: gm-techniques, fate, new-players, social, group-dynamics

I have little experience GMing Fate. In fact, my only experience so far is a "twosie"/one-on-one one-shot with my best friend, Z. I've been researching an enormous amount of materials, as well as reading both manuals, and after a gargantual overcomplication failure with D&D I'm very afraid of failing with Fate as well.

Z has been around for most of my research and is quite well-acquainted with the rules of the game, as well as the fundamental conceptual differences between D&D and lighter systems. She's going to have her character readily-made, whereas the others will make them during the first session.

Neither of us are in any way experts, but I've documented myself and prepared a lot, and Z has a feel for the game and a willingness to help me that I feel will help me quite a bit. So how can I have her, as something of a "GM lieutenant", help me get the other players invested and acquainted to the game better? What are a few concrete ways that she can be a bridge between me and the others?

Comment: Which Fate-powered game are you playing?

Comment: Fate Accelerated

Answer (score 7):

## Do Not Pre-Make a Character

Assuming you are running Fate Core, FAE, Diaspora, Dresden Files, Spirit of the Century, or any Fate variant that I know of, you should **not do this**.

You are depriving Z, the other players, and **your game** of the spontaneous, synthetic, synergistic effects of creating characters in conjunction with one another. In Fate, character creation is part of play. If you've been reading the books, you know that already. Don't truncate the play experience of your group.

Z is welcome to come to the first session with a strong concept for her character, but the exact details of the character should emerge as a result of interactions with the rest of the group. Her character will be tied in more closely with the group and the setting that way, and you're likely to get more interesting, more exciting aspects as a result. Aspects are levers that you can pull as a GM during play - you want them to be interesting and meaningful. Don't deprive yourself of the sparks struck during character creation.

## Don't Worry Too Much - You're Not Alone

In Fate, the players have plenty of narrative control. It's not your job to tell a story all alone.

In Fate, the players have lots of knowledge about the circumstances of the fiction. It's not your job to manage every interaction of the rules all alone.

In Fate, the players are going to want to get Fate points. It's not your job to compel their aspects all alone.

In Fate, it is the job of every player to make everyone look awesome. It's not your job to try to be awesome all alone.

In Fate, the GM is a player. You get to play. Enjoy the game. Turn questions back on the group. Share the load. Share the fun.

## It's Easier Than You Think

Your friend Z can help without being a rules lawyer. You don't need a GM lieutenant because every player has narrative power, because you don't keep a lot of secrets, because you don't need to control the whole story, because you don't have to manage everyone's aspects.